# c++ return a string held inside a deleted dynamic object

Tags: c++

DISCLAIMER: Java developer learning C++.

What happens when you return a string held inside an deleted dynamic object?

here's a fairly standard dequeue method and I want to make it work *without* using a pointer for the templated data, which is a string in my test case.

g++ on Ubuntu 13.04 gives me segfault. On the latest OSX, my data is corrupted.

Is it my code or C++?

```
// remove an object from the front of the queue.
// the test case instantiate T as string. 
// front->data is assigned an static string.
template<class T>
T & SomeQueue<T>::dequeue() {
    if (empty()) throw runtime_error("kaboom");

    T tmp = front->data;
    Node<T> *n = front;
    front = front->next;
    delete n;

    return tmp;
};
```

Comment: Define "string". If you mean a `char *` and are using `Node<char*>` as the underlying type, then simply don't do that. Use `std::string` as the formal node type. And in fact, use `std::queue<std::string>` instead and avoid all the head-slamming on the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As john says, the copy of the deleted object is fine. It crashes because you are returning a reference to a local variable (`tmp`). When the function returns, this object no longer exists, so you can't use it. Change `T & SomeQueue<T>::dequeue` into `T SomeQueue<T>::dequeue` so you return a copy of a `T` object, rather than a reference.

(And, if you enable warnings when you compile, most compilers will tell you about this sort of thing).

Comment: +1 One little ampersand. I didn't even see it. Nice catch, sir.

Comment: reference is a wonderful idea. i'm sure i'll master it someday. :)

Comment: You can do most things with references, but you should NEVER return a reference to something that will disappear!

Answer (score 3):

This code is OK, because you *copied* the string before deleteing the object. The cause of the segfault is something else.

**Correction:**

The problem is here

```
template<class T>
T & SomeQueue<T>::dequeue() {
```

should be

```
template<class T>
T SomeQueue<T>::dequeue() {
```

don't return references to local variables. The local variable is destroyed, that's what's giving you a reference to something that has been destroyed.

Answer (score 3):

That code is just fine, the reason for segfault is that you are returning a reference to a local variable which gets destroyed upon function exit.

```
T tmp = front->data;
Node<T> *n = front;
front = front->next;
delete n;

return tmp; //tmp is a local variable here. You are returning a reference (T&)
```